# Unable to resolve the instance in Webapp program.cs in c# .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, events, dependency-injection

I have 4 c# projects

- `WebApp` (ASP.NET Core MVC web application)
- `EmailNotificationService` (class library)
- `PushNotificationService` (class library)
- `EventBroker` (class library)

In the web app, I have a background service running, which continuously listens to  a queue (injected as singleton). The queue gets updated by the web app and the background service reads from the queue and processes each item and then uploads it to the db. The background service also contains an instance of `EventManager` (injected in singleton), using which it publishes the upload event

```
public class UploadBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly UploadQueue _workerQueue;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<UploadQueue> _logger;
    private readonly EventManager _eventManager;

    public UploadBackgroundService (UploadQueue workerQueue, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<UploadQueue > logger, EventManager eventManager)
    {
        _workerQueue = workerQueue ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workerQueue));
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        _eventManager = eventManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventManager));
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                using IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
                using DbContext dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext >() ?? throw new Exception("Database context is null!");

                await foreach(Func<DbContext , Task<Models.UploadResult>> workItem in this._workerQueue.ReadAsyncStream())
                {
                    UploadResult uploadResult = await workItem(dbContext);
                    _eventManager.NotifyObservers(new UploadResult(Enums.UploadStatus.Error));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `EventBroker` project contains an `EventManager` class that creates an upload event and notify all its subscribers.

```
public class EventManager
{
    public event EventHandler<UploadEventArgs>? UploadEvent;

    public  virtual void OnUpload(UploadEventArgs uploadEventArgs)
    {
        UploadEvent?.Invoke(this, uploadEventArgs);
    }

    public void NotifyObservers(object uploadResult)
    {
        UploadEventArgs uploadEventArgs = new UploadEventArgs();
        uploadEventArgs.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uploadResult);
        OnUpload(uploadEventArgs);
    }
    
}
```

The `EmailNotificationsService` contains an email consumer class, that subscribes to the upload event in EventManager and whenever it gets notified sends an email to the users.

```
public class EmailConsumer : IConsumer
{
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public EmailConsumer(IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(emailSender));
    }

    public void Subscribe(EventManager eventBroker)
    {
        eventBroker.UploadEvent += SendEmailNotifications!;
    }

    public void SendEmailNotifications(object sender, UploadEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        EmailUploadResult uploadResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailUploadResult>(eventArgs.Data) ?? throw new InvalidDataException("Corrupt data");
        _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(null, new List<Address> { new Address("testcapsdev@outlook.com") }, null, null, null, uploadResult);
    }
}
```

The `PushNotificationsService` contains the signalRNotification consumer class, that subscribes to the upload event in EventManager and whenever it gets notified sends push notifications to the UI.

```
public class SignalRNotificationConsumer: IConsumer
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub, INotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public SignalRNotificationConsumer(IHubContext<NotificationHub, INotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public void Subscribe(EventManager eventBroker)
    {
        eventBroker.UploadEvent += SendSignalRNotifications!;
    }

    private void SendSignalRNotifications(object sender, UploadEventArgs uploadEventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            SignalRUploadResult uploadResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignalRUploadResult >(uploadEventArgs.Data) ?? throw new InvalidDataException("Corrupt data");
            _hubContext.Clients.All.UploadNotifications(uploadResult);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am subscribing to event inside the web app `program.cs`:

```
var services = builder.Services;

services.AddSingleton<UploadQueue, UploadQueue>();
services.AddSingleton<EventManager, EventManager>();
services.AddScoped<SignalRNotificationConsumer>().AddScoped<IConsumer, SignalRNotificationConsumer>(s => s.GetService<SignalRNotificationConsumer>()!);
services.AddScoped<EmailConsumer>().AddScoped<IConsumer, EmailConsumer>(s => s.GetService<EmailConsumer>()!);
services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

var app = builder.Build();

EventManager eventBroker = app.ServiceProvider.GetService<EventManager>()!;
IConsumer consumer = (IConsumer)app.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EmailConsumer))!;
consumer.Subscribe(eventBroker);
IConsumer consumer =  (IConsumer)app.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SignalRNotificationConsumer))!;
consumer.Subscribe(eventBroker);
```

Now I am getting an error

> Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider

I don't want to subscribe inside the background service which works fine. Because background service doesn't have to know anything about the subscribers.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    IConsumer signalRConsumer = (IConsumer)_serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SignalRNotificationConsumer))! ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("SignalRConsumer");
    IConsumer emailConsumer = (IConsumer)_serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EmailConsumer))! ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("SignalRConsumer");

    signalRConsumer.Subscribe(_eventManager);
    emailConsumer.Subscribe(_eventManager);

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
            try
            {
                using IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
                using DbContext dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext >() ?? throw new Exception("Database context is null!");

                await foreach(Func<DbContext , Task<Models.UploadResult>> workItem in this._workerQueue.ReadAsyncStream())
                {
                    UploadResult uploadResult = await workItem(dbContext);
                    _eventManager.NotifyObservers(new UploadResult(Enums.UploadStatus.Error));
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine.

So could someone please point out the right direction. Is my thought appropriate? and how do I make this work without having the background service initializing the subscribers.

Comment: You need to pass the subscriber to the background service and initialize the subscriber before you start the background service.  If you put the subscribers a class you can pass the entire class to the background service.  Class object are pass by Ref so changes will bee seen by the main class the the background class.